# Fedora 25 : Gnome Software Center and Curl not working behind proxy

Tags: fedora, gnome, curl, proxy, packagekit

**Update - I'm on Fedora 25 now but the issue is still unsolved.**

I have Fedora 25 Workstation on my laptop. The internet access is through proxy server only.

I have successfully configured proxy settings for `dnf` and `wget`. I can install and updates packages using dnf from terminal. `wget` and firefox also work.

But Gnome Software Center and `curl` do not work. Everytime I try to install something from software center, I get the error

> Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for
>   https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-24&arch=x86_64
>   [Failed to connect to mirrors.fedoraproject.org port 443: Connection
>   refused]

What I have tried so far:

1 : Set proxy settings using `dconf-editor`  **[(Source)](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/81944/gnome-software-ignore-proxy-settings/)**

2 : Manually add proxy info to `/etc/PackageKit/PackageKit.conf`  **[(Source1)](https://github.com/JoliOS/packagekit/blob/master/etc/PackageKit.conf.in)** **[(Source2)](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PackageKit_Frequently_Asked_Questions#PackageKit_won.27t_work_with_my_proxy_server)**

3 : Add proxy info to `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.curlrc`, `/etc/profile` **[(Source)](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Fedora_24&p=squid&f=2)**

None of these have worked.

How do I get Gnome Software Center working?

Answer (score 1):

You could try working around this by adding `proxy=...` after every single `metalink=` line in `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo`.  I haven't tested this, but these are *only* config files which the PackageKit daemon will accept proxy settings from.  Support for setting a proxy in /etc/PackageKit has been removed.

What's supposed to happen, is the PackageKit client sets a proxy.  With `pkcon` (console command) this is based on environment variables; with GNOME Software, it is based on the GNOME proxy setting.  I think neither of these work correctly at the moment though:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1348843

> In a corporate environment, with proxy only web access, I configure
>   through the GUI the HTTP, HTTPS and FTP proxy.
>
> When I use "Software", nothing happens. I can browse the catalog, but
>   install does not work.
>
> If I use "pkcon" from command-line, I get an error:
>
> ```
> […@… ~]$ LC_ALL=C pkcon -v update
> 10:04:32  PackageKit          Verbose debugging enabled (on console 1)
> 10:04:32  PackageKit          failed to set proxy: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._pk_2dengine_2derror_2dquark.Code3: setting the proxy failed
> Command failed: The proxy could not be set: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._pk_2dengine_2derror_2dquark.Code3: setting the proxy failed
> ```
>
> "dnf" works, and the environment is correctly set.
>
> If I unset in the shell all proxy, pkcon tries to download, but fails,
>   obviously.
>
> Version-Release number of selected component (if applicable): I'm
>   using latest PackageKit on F24 :
>   1.1.1-3.fc24

...

> Just updated to F25 final, still the same bug.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a old thread, but I just came across the same problem using Fedora in a corporate environment with as proxy server.

The link to the issue provided by [sourcejedi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29483/sourcejedi) in his answer got some attention in 2018, where Kevin Kofler stated

> You need to set the ProxyHTTP= in /etc/PackageKit/PackageKit.conf

I tried this, and it actually worked for me. I just wanted to add this here, since it is one of the first results on Google for the problem and other people might come across this post.